# How to add 1 to right of above cell

Tags: excel, vba

I have a cell that contains 19 characters of numbers. Because of its length Excel can't show the whole number till you change the cell format to Text.

Now the A1 Value is 3310195401193581830.

Autofill series won't work because the cell format is Text.

So I just split the value into two parts:

```vb
Dim SerialIDR, SerialIDL As String
SerialIDR = Right(ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Value, 9)
SerialIDL = Left(ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Value, 10)
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A2").Value = SerialIDL & SerialIDR + 1

SerialIDR = Right(ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Value, 9)
SerialIDL = Left(ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Value, 10)
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A3").Value = SerialIDL & SerialIDR + 2

SerialIDR = Right(ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Value, 9)
SerialIDL = Left(ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Value, 10)
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A4").Value = SerialIDL & SerialIDR + 3
```

How do I get the 19 character number then loop through a column and autofill series this value for X cells in column.

Like this:
3310195401193581830
3310195401193581831
3310195401193581832
...

Comment: Try WorksheetFunction.Len - see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/len-function

Comment: Also try: `Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("A1:A11"), Type:=xlFillSeries`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Autofill Integer String Series

```vb
Sub AutoFillIntegerStringSeries()
    
    ' Reference the worksheet ('ws')
    ' in the workbook containing this code ('ThisWorkbook').
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    
    ' Reference the range ('rg'). Its first cell holds
    ' the initial integer string.
    Dim rg As Range: Set rg = ws.Range("A1:A10")
    
    ' Store the number of rows in a variable ('rCount').
    Dim rCount As Long: rCount = rg.Rows.Count - 1 ' not counting the first cell
    ' Validate the number of rows.
    If rCount = 0 Then Exit Sub ' there is just one row containing the string

    ' Store the initial string in a variable ('CurrentString').
    Dim CurrentString As String: CurrentString = CStr(rg.Cells(1).Value)
    ' Using the 'IsDigits' function, validate the initial string.
    If Not IsDigits(CurrentString) Then Exit Sub ' not all characters are digits
    
    ' Define an array ('Data') to hold the resulting integer strings.
    Dim Data() As String: ReDim Data(1 To rCount, 1 To 1)
    
    ' Declare variables.
    Dim r As Long ' Current Array Row (Element)
    
    ' Loop through the rows of the array.
    For r = 1 To rCount
        ' Using the 'IncrementIntegerString' function on the current string,
        ' store the incremented integer string in the same variable.
        CurrentString = IncrementIntegerString(CurrentString)
        ' Write the incremented string to the current row of the array.
        Data(r, 1) = CurrentString
    Next r

    ' Write the values from the array to the range excluding the first cell.
    rg.Resize(rCount).Offset(1).Value = Data

End Sub

''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
' Purpose:      Returns a boolean indicating whether all characters of a string
'               are digits.
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
Function IsDigits(ByVal s As String) As Boolean
    If Len(s) > 0 Then IsDigits = s Like String(Len(s), "#")
End Function

''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
' Purpose:      Returns an integer string which is by one greater than
'               the given integer string ('IntegerString').
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
Function IncrementIntegerString(ByVal IntegerString As String) As String
    
    Dim iLen As Long: iLen = Len(IntegerString)
    
    Dim Digit As Long
    Dim n As Long
    
    For n = iLen To 1 Step -1
        Digit = CLng(Mid(IntegerString, n, 1))
        If Digit <> 9 Then Exit For
    Next n
    
    If n = 0 Then
        IncrementIntegerString = "1" & String(iLen, "0")
    Else
        IncrementIntegerString = Left(IntegerString, n - 1) _
            & CStr(Digit + 1) & String(iLen - n, "0")
    End If
    
End Function
```